# eyefi-config with 2GB eyefi card?

Tags: wireless, hardware, photography

So I bought a [$7 Eye-Fi card](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2GB-Eye-FI-SD-Wireless-2G-Share-WIFI-Flash-Memory-Card-for-Digital-Camera-/152132542611?hash=item236bce6093:g:EggAAOSwjXRXYUbF).  After all, there's a [linux config utility](https://sr71.net/projects/eyefi/) and a [standalone linux server](https://github.com/dgrant/eyefiserver2), so the fact that Ricoh has killed their cloud server shouldn't really matter, right?

Apparently it does matter.

Even after finding a hidden mailing-list post detailing how to setup the virgin card such that `eyefi-config` can find it (see answer below), it is still unable to find the local server.

I've got the server on the local segment, even connecting by wifi on the same access point.  The server is exposed to the network, I can telnet to port 59278 from another host on the same network.

But mysteriously, the card can't find the server in test mode, never attempts to access it (according to the server log) and even the card's log never shows an attempted upload.

Any suggestions are appreciated... but for now, this card is going into the long-term storage bin.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer (still not working)**

The author of eyefi-config had a mailing list about it for a while.  Deep in the mailing list, I found [a post detailing the procedure for the similar X2 card](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/eyefi-config-discuss/Goz_BOHvORw).

Basically, the answer is to create the following files:

```
cd /media/NAME_HERE_OF_CARD
mkdir -p EyeFi
dd if=/dev/zero bs=16384 count=1 of=EyeFi/reqm
dd if=/dev/zero bs=16384 count=1 of=EyeFi/reqc
dd if=/dev/zero bs=16384 count=1 of=EyeFi/rspm
dd if=/dev/zero bs=16384 count=1 of=EyeFi/rspc
```

The rest of the setup procedure appears to be what's detailed in the README.

I don't actually have it working yet, but until I have further evidence, I'm blaming that on the server.

Comment: Did this ever work?  I pulled out an old camera from storage, and we don't have the original laptop anymore.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put any more time into it.  Would appreciate an update if you explore further though.